# How to detect for when there isn't a specific entity near a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a freestanding crawling system that works for multiplayer in version 1.15. I was wondering if there would be a way to summon an entity to the player when that specific entity is not near the player. Here are the commands that I have so far:

```
/scoreboard objectives add sneak minecraft.custom:minecraft.sneak_time

/execute as @a[scores={sneak=1}] at @s run tp @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,distance=..2] ~ ~-1 ~

/execute as @a[scores={sneak=1..}] run scoreboard players reset @a sneak

/execute as @a[scores={sneak=1}] at @s unless entity @e[tag=IsCrawl,distance=3..,limit=1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,Tags:["IsCrawl"],Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:shulker",Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,CustomNameVisible:0b,DeathLootTable:"minecraft:empty",AttachFace:0b,Tags:["IsCrawl"],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:1000000,ShowParticles:0b}]}]}

/execute as @a at @s if entity @e[tag=IsCrawl,distance=3..,limit=1] run kill @e[tag=IsCrawl]
```

I've also tried this (formatted for clarity, run unformatted):

```
execute as @a at @s unless entity @e[tag=IsCrawl,distance=3..,limit=1] 
run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {
    NoGravity:1b,
    Invisible:1b,
    NoBasePlate:1b,
    Tags:["IsCrawl"],
    Passengers:[{
        id:"minecraft:shulker",
        Silent:1b,
        Invulnerable:1b,
        CustomNameVisible:0b,
        DeathLootTable:"minecraft:empty",
        AttachFace:0b,T
        ags:["IsCrawl"],
        ActiveEffects:[{
            Id:14b,
            Amplifier:1b,
            Duration:1000000,
            ShowParticles:0b
        }]
    }]
}
```

But I need one that only summons when the player has a sneak score of 1 and when the entity is not near the player.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a few more details.  I don't fully understand the problem.

Comment: I just need help with detecting for when an entity is not near the player.

Comment: There's an `execute` variant similar to `execute if` that inverts the result; `execute unless`.  You're most of the way there already with your last command.

Comment: I made a command like this: execute as @a at @s unless entity @e[tag=IsCrawl,distance=3..,limit=1] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,Tags:["IsCrawl"],Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:shulker",Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,CustomNameVisible:0b,DeathLootTable:"minecraft:empty",AttachFace:0b,Tags:["IsCrawl"],ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:1000000,ShowParticles:0b}]}]}

Comment: But I need one that only summons when the player has a sneak score of 1 and when the entity is not near the player

Comment: You're using `execute unless` in your given commands already. So what's your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

try making it so the entity sets your player a dummy score of 2 when within a certain radius and having the game subtract the dummy by 1 every tick.

if the score reaches 0, summon a new entity

Answer (score 0):

So in pseudocode, you want:

```
if(sneak = 1 & distance > 3) {
    summon();
}
```

Your current command would only summon if one already exists, and further away than 2 tiles. I presume you also want to summon if there are no armor stands tagged `IsCrawl`

Conditionals with commas apply the `AND` operation in minecraft. However, there is no `OR` function for conditionals, and `NOT` applies to all. So you would need to use multiple commands if you used negation due to [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), which state.

```
 ¬A & ¬B = ¬(A | B)
 ¬(A & B) = ¬A | ¬B
```

I don't think there's a need for this complexity though. The operation `distance >= 3` is the inverse of `distance <= 2`, so why not just use:

```
 tag=IsCrawl,distance=..2
```

as your conditional? If there is **not** 'one or more entity within the radius', then there are no entities within the radius, hence you want to summon a new one. (See: [Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)))That would lead to

```
@a[scores={sneak=1}] at @s unless entity @e[tag=IsCrawl,distance=..2]
```